# NativeScript Vue - set focus on TextField

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using NativeScript `("nativescript-vue": "^2.5.0")` testing on iOS 13

```
"tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
```

Trying to set focus to on TextField when taping a button, it currently looks like this

```
  <GridLayout dock="top" columns="auto,*,auto" width="70%" rows="auto,auto">
    <Label text.decode="&#xf2bd;" horizontalAlignment="left" row="0" rowSpan="2"  col="0" />
    <Label text="USER" horizontalAlignment="left" row="0" col="1" class="m-l-3" />
    <Label :text="userEditBtnText"  @tap="userEditTap()"  horizontalAlignment="right" row="0" rowSpan="2" col="2" class="btnEdit"/>
    <TextField ref="userid" text="@username" :editable="userEdit" horizontalAlignment="left" row="1" col="1" class="m-l-3"/>
  </GridLayout>
```

and the code for  @tap="userEditTap()"

```
userEditTap(){
  this.userEdit = true;
  this.userEditBtnText="SAVE";
  this.$refs["userid"].focus();      
}
```

and my console error:

> JavaScript error: file:
>   node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.ios.js:312:26
>   JS ERROR Error: NativeScript encountered a fatal error: TypeError:
>   this.$refs["userid"].focus is not a function. (In
>   'this.$refs["userid"].focus()', 'this.$refs["userid"].focus' is
>   undefined)

any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access by `ref` you are accessing the Vue element, you will have to call `.nativeView` to access the actual TextField.

It should be,

```
this.$refs["userid"].nativeView.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks, it takes two taps on the Label to get the focus but I can live with this for now! Any insight on what could be causing this behaviour ? I tried       `this.$refs["userid"].nativeView.focus(); `
`this.$forceUpdate();`
but it does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you can share a Playground sample it's easy to debug that.

Comment: Sure thing, check this out
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Pnlbwc

If you tap edit once the field becomes editable but is not focused, when you tap it again it focuses as should

Comment: Did you paste the link? Also confirm which platform & device you are running the test on.

Comment: Im testing this on an iPhone 7 iOS 13, yes I pasted the link, I keep hitting return without the shift!!@#$

Comment: It's because you are binding `userEdit` flag to `editable` attribute of TextField which is initially set to false. Upon your first click you toggling the flag but the change detection cycle runs after that and takes a while for textfield to be editable. Hence focus is not working the first time. Either wait for editable property to change (use property change listeners) Or update textfield editable from JS instead of model binding so the change will be instant and respond to focus immediately.